# How to override the default right click behavior in web using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, contextmenu, blazor-webassembly

In a web application, when right-clicking, a context menu is typically displayed. I want to override this default behavior and show my custom menu instead. I've written the following code. However, the issue I'm facing is that both the default context menu and my custom context menu are being displayed. I want to display only my custom context menu and not the default one.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    window.showContextMenu = (id, name, width, height, locationX, locationY) => {
        var contextMenu = document.getElementById("contextMenu");
        contextMenu.style.position = "absolute";
        contextMenu.style.left = locationX + "px";
        contextMenu.style.top = locationY + "px";
        contextMenu.style.display = "block";

        contextMenu.innerHTML = `
            <ul>
                <li>Id: ${id}</li>
                <li>Name: ${name}</li>
                <li>Width: ${width}</li>
                <li>Height: ${height}</li>
                <li>LocationX: ${locationX}</li>
                <li>LocationY: ${locationY}</li>
            </ul>
        `;

        // Create the close button element
        const closeButton = document.createElement("button");
        closeButton.textContent = "Close";
        closeButton.id = "closeButton";

        // Add a click event listener to the close button
        closeButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
            contextMenu.style.display = "none";
        });

        // Append the close button to the context menu
        contextMenu.appendChild(closeButton);
    };


    const contextMenu = document.getElementById("contextMenu");
    contextMenu.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});



const contextMenu = document.getElementById("contextMenu");
contextMenu.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I tried e.preventDefault(), but it's not working as expected.
The above code is the part of Blazor WebAssembly App
showContextMenu() is called from the razor template on the click event of image.

Comment: you are not describing the behavior properly. your menu never shows because `showContextMenu` is never called

Comment: Thanks, dear, I have updated my query. FYI it's called from HTML page on the right click of the image.

Comment: try call `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: Not working dear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're only preventing the default behavior on your custom context menu, not on the entire document or target element where the right-click is intended.
To prevent the default context menu from showing up, you should attach the contextmenu event listener to the entire document or the specific target element and call e.preventDefault() there. Ensure the listener is added before the right-click occurs on the desired element.

Here's a proposed implementation:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();  // Prevent default context menu from showing up
        showContextMenu();
    });
});

function showContextMenu() {
    var contextMenu = document.getElementById("contextMenu");
    
    // ... 

    contextMenu.style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Your solution worked buddy, only you forgot to pass the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

HTML file:

```
<div id="rmenu" class="hide">
<ul>
            <li>Id: ${id}</li>
            <li>Name: ${name}</li>
            <li>Width: ${width}</li>
            <li>Height: ${height}</li>
            <li>LocationX: ${locationX}</li>
            <li>LocationY: ${locationY}</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

CSS file:

```
.hide {
opacity: 0;
}

.show {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #5c5e63;
  color: #ECECEC;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

JS file:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', contextMenu);
document.addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.getElementById("rmenu").className = "hide";
 })

const contextMenu = (e) => {
        document.getElementById("rmenu").className = "show";
        document.getElementById("rmenu").style.top = mouseY(e) + 'px';
        document.getElementById("rmenu").style.left = mouseX(e) + 'px';
        findSelected(e.target.getAttribute('id'));
        window.event.returnValue = false;
    }


export function mouseX(evt) {
    if (evt.pageX) {
        return evt.pageX;
    } else if (evt.clientX) {
        return evt.clientX + (document.documentElement.scrollLeft ?
            document.documentElement.scrollLeft :
            document.div.scrollLeft);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

export function mouseY(evt) {
    if (evt.pageY) {
        return evt.pageY;
    } else if (evt.clientY) {
        return evt.clientY + (document.documentElement.scrollTop ?
            document.documentElement.scrollTop :
            document.body.scrollTop);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).